# How to set cors setting

Tags: go, cors, go-gin

my project uses go-gin, and I tried setting cors

When I submitted the following code,

```
package middleware

import (
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func Use() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

    cors.Default()
    return
}
```

```
func main() {
    log.Printf("Server started")

    r := gin.Default()

    route.Route(r)

    middleware.Use()

    log.Fatal(r.Run(":8080"))
}
```

it was pointed out that cors did not work, and this method worked fine with the application I created before, but I do not know what the problem is with this application

Comment: You never passed the cors middleware to the router. See the cors package readme for a full example: https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors#canonical-example

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting cors Default in your router correctly

check this basic example from the docs

```
func main() {
router := gin.Default()
router.Use(cors.Default()) // <- you are missing this step
router.Run()
}
```

The middleware.Use() that you do, doesn't set the cors to your router

Check [this github docs page](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) for more info about the topic

Comment: thanks!!

i missed setting so change code

```
func main() {
    log.Printf("Server started")

    r := gin.Default()
   r.Use(middleware,Use())

    route.Route(r)


    log.Fatal(r.Run(":8080"))
}
```

Also, thanks to cors being placed and set in front of route to reflect the influence of CORS on the router